# Laravel hasOne Relation 2 columns

Tags: laravel, lumen, relation, has-one

I have 2 Models first one is(Plan) and the second is (PlanPrice)

I have this columns in table plan_price:

`$table->float('price')->comment('Price for one month or one year depends 
 on country code');
$table->string('country_code')->default('EG');`

What I want is to get a plan with price depends on the user country code.

Comment: Why does the relationship need to know about your enum type?  It's going to return a row with both monthly and annual regardless, isn't it?

Comment: I need to get the price depend on the type.


 public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PlanPrice::class, 'plan_id');
    }

Comment: But you have both monthly and annual on the same row.  So what determines the "type" in plan price?  Why would you have more than one plan price's if you have a type setting on plan?

Comment: you suggest to separate type ?

Comment: I just don't understand your logic here.  You have a type on plan, then why do you need one on prices?

Comment: every plan has price one for annual and another monthly

i need to get the price depend on the plan type

Comment: Then why would you have an enum type on the plan itself? And why would you have more than one row of a price when you have two columns for annual and monthly

Comment: what's your suggestion ?

Comment: I don't have one because your structure/intention doesn't make logical sense.  That's why I'm asking these questions.

Comment: thank you i got it now.
the price should not seperated.

Comment: the plan price should be like that:
"price" column instead of the (annual and monthly)

Comment: Ok, that explains why you'd have more than one price, but the type column on plan still doesn't make sense with your statement: `every plan has price one for annual and another monthly`

Comment: the problem with me that i need to separate price on it's table because the price
depends on currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do this:

```
return $this->hasOne(PlanPrice::class, 'plan_id')->where('country_code', 
$what_ever_your_code_is);
```

Comment: That's really not flexible.   How is the country code supposed to be passed to this relationship method and how is it supposed to support multiple country codes?   It'd be better to use a query scope that queries this relationship on a given country code and not use a country code in the relationship definition.